# REST source in Azure data flow retrieving an xml file results in corrupt record

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I've got a source in data flow that calls a rest API.  This is the call:  https://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/MEI_CLI/CSCICP03.USA.M/OECD?startTime=2020-01&format=compact_v2

When I do data preview, I get _corrupt_record.  If I get the result of the call through postman and save it in a data lake as an XML file and use that as a source, it works fine.  Any advice?

[setup[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpWqV.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Copy activity to make REST API call and store REST response as XML in datalake and from there use dataflow to pick that data to process further.

Comment: I would like to do that but XML is not available as a type for the sink within the copy activity.  Is there something I can do to make XML an available type in the copy activity?